# Apache rewrite that strips anything after a pipe (|) character

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

TL;DR:

Requests coming in for `https://example.com/page%7chttps://example.com`

Want to 301 to `https://example.com/page`

Rule of `RewriteRule ^(.*?)\%7C $1 [NC,R=301,L]` not working and I don't know why.

Long Version:

I am seeing a lot of 404 errors coming in from a directory site that have some screwy code and I have been trying to get them fixed but not making any progress. I am now trying to simply redirect them once they get to me.

The structure of their bad links is `https://example.com/page%7chttps://example.com`

What I am trying to do is simply rip off from the %7C onward. A regex to get that into group 1 would be `^(.*?)\%7C`

So I figured I would simply need to do something like
`RewriteRule ^(.*?)\%7C $1 [NC,R=301,L]` but that is still returning the original request just with the | character instead of the hex value 7C.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am getting a large number of such requests (with `%7C`) from google's crawler. Did you eventually figure out the `RewriteRule` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `RewriteRule ^(.*)\| $1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.